# Problems coding c++ in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm having trouble when I try to run my codes in Eclipse. Not a problem of what I write, since the basic code that comes written when I create a "helloWorld" project has the same problem.

The programm simply says: "Launching name.exe" has encountered a problem. Error starting process. 
Then, when I click on "See Details", this is what it says:

```
Error starting process.
Cannot run program "C:\C\eclipse\workspace\Precios\Debug\Precios.exe": Launching failed
Cannot run program "C:\C\eclipse\workspace\Precios\Debug\Precios.exe": Launching failed
Cannot run program "C:\C\eclipse\workspace\Precios\Debug\Precios.exe": Launching failed
```

I installed the programm in my notebook exactly the same way and ran the same codes and didn't face any trouble.

It would be really helpful if someone could lend a hand, it's really annoying and I need it to continue my homework!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to include some code, There is not enough information to help. Try some You Tube videos. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny1RbJNgxhc. I am not endorsing this but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: "C:\C\eclipse\workspace\Precios\Debug\Precios.exe" This path looks odd, is it really supposed to start with "C:\C\eclipse"? shouldnt it be just "C:\eclipse" ?